# Why is my code so much slower in function form?

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, function

I wrote a code a while ago that processes spectra using data from text files and performing calculations on them. I started with a code that just does everything line-by-line without any functions, and despite being long, it finishes running in 2.11 seconds (according to `%%timeit`). Below is that original code, labeled as such.

However, I wanted to put my code into functions instead, to allow for easier readability and usage with different models in the future. Even though I'm using all the same steps as I did before (but this time inside my functions), it is so much slower. This code is also below. Now, I have to wait for about 15-20 minutes to get the same outputs. Why is it so much slower, and is there any way I can make it significantly faster but still use functions?

Original Code:

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
filename = 'bpass_spectra.txt'
extinctionfile = 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt' # from R_V = 4.0
pointslist = []
datalist = []
speclist = []

# Constants
Msun = 1.98892e30 # solar mass [kg]
h = 4.1357e-15 # Planck's constant [eV s]
c = float(3e8) # speed of light [m/s]

# Read spectra file
f = open(filename, 'r')
rawspectra = f.readlines()
met = re.findall('Z\s=\s(\d*\.\d+)', rawspectra[0])
del rawspectra[0]
for i in range(len(rawspectra)):
    newlist = rawspectra[i].split(' ')
    datalist.append(newlist)

# Read extinction curve data file
rawpoints = open(extinctionfile, 'r').readlines()
for i in range(len(rawpoints)):
    newlst = re.split('(?!\S)\s(?=\S)|(?!\S)\s+(?=\S)', rawpoints[i])
    pointslist.append(newlst)
pointslist = pointslist[3:]
lambdalist = [float(item[0]) for item in pointslist]
k_abslist = [float(item[4]) for item in pointslist]
xvallist = [(c*h)/(lamb*1e-6) for lamb in lambdalist]
k_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xvallist, k_abslist)

# Create new lists
Elist = [float(item[0]) for item in datalist]
speclambdalist = [h*c*1e9/E for E in Elist]
z1list = [float(item[1]) for item in datalist]
speclist.extend(z1list)
met = met[0]
klist = [None]*len(speclist)
Loutlist = [None]*len(speclist)
Tlist = [None]*len(speclist)

# Define parameters
b = 2.0
R = 1.0
z = 1.0
Mgas = 1.0 # mass of gas, input
Mhalo = 2e41 # mass of dark matter halo, known
if float(met) > 0.0052:
    DGRlist = [50.0*np.exp(-2.21)*float(met)]*len(speclist)
elif float(met) <= 0.0052:
    DGRlist = [((50.0*float(met))**3.15)*np.exp(-0.96)]*len(speclist)
for i in range(len(speclist)):
    if float(Elist[i]) <= 4.1357e-3: # frequencies <= 10^12 Hz
        klist[i] = 0.1*(float(Elist[i])/(1000.0*h))**b # extinction law [cm^2/g]
    elif float(Elist[i]) > 4.1357e-3: # frequencies > 10^12 Hz
        klist[i] = k_interp(Elist[i]) # interpolated function's value at Elist[i]
Mdustlist = [Mgas*DGR for DGR in DGRlist] # dust mass
Rhalo = 0.784*(0.27**2.0)*(0.7**(-2.0/3.0))*float(10.0/(1.0+z))*((Mhalo/(1e8*Msun))**(1.0/3.0))
Rdust = 0.018*Rhalo # [kpc]

for i in range(len(speclist)):
    Tlist[i] = 3*Mdustlist[i]*klist[i]/(4*np.pi*Rdust)

Linlist = [float(spectra)*R for spectra in speclist]

# Outgoing luminosity as function of wavelength
for i in range(len(Linlist)):
    Loutlist[i] = Linlist[i]*np.exp(-Tlist[i])

# Test the calculation
print "LIN ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000:", Linlist[0], Linlist[1000]
print "LOUT ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000:", Loutlist[0], Loutlist[1000]
```

New "function-ized" Code (much slower):

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

# Required files and lists
filename = 'bpass_spectra.txt' # number of columns = 4
extinctionfile = 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt' # R_V = 4.0
datalist = []
if filename == 'bpass_spectra.txt':
    filetype = 4
else:
    filetype = 1
if extinctionfile == 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt':
    R_V = 4.0
else:
    R_V = 1.0 #to be determined

# Constants
M_sun = 1.98892e30 # solar mass [kg]
h = 4.1357e-15 # Planck's constant [eV s]
c = float(3e8) # speed of light [m/s]

# Inputs
beta = 2.0
R = 1.0
z = 1.0
M_gas = 1.0
M_halo = 2e41

# Read spectra file
f = open(filename, 'r')
rawlines = f.readlines()
met = re.findall('Z\s=\s(\d*\.\d+)', rawlines[0])
del rawlines[0]
for i in range(len(rawlines)):
    newlist = rawlines[i].split(' ')
    datalist.append(newlist)

# Read extinction curve data file
rawpoints = open(extinctionfile, 'r').readlines()
def interpolate(R_V, rawpoints, Elist, j):
    pointslist = []
    if R_V == 4.0:
        for i in range(len(rawpoints)):
            newlst = re.split('(?!\S)\s(?=\S)|(?!\S)\s+(?=\S)', rawpoints[i])
            pointslist.append(newlst)
        pointslist = pointslist[3:]
        lambdalist = [float(item[0]) for item in pointslist]
        k_abslist = [float(item[4]) for item in pointslist]
        xvallist = [(c*h)/(lamb*1e-6) for lamb in lambdalist]
        k_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xvallist, k_abslist)
        return k_interp(Elist[j])

# Dust extinction function
def dust(interpolate, filetype, datalist, beta, R, z, M_gas, M_halo, met):
    speclist = []
    if filetype == 4:
        metallicity = float(met[0])
        Elist = [float(item[0]) for item in datalist]
        speclambdalist = [h*c*1e9/E for E in Elist]
        met1list = [float(item[1]) for item in datalist]
        speclist.extend(met1list)
        klist, Tlist = [None]*len(speclist), [None]*len(speclist)
        if metallicity > 0.0052:
            DGRlist = [50.0*np.exp(-2.21)*metallicity]*len(speclist) # dust to gas ratio
        elif metallicity <= 0.0052:
            DGRlist = [((50.0*metallicity)**3.15)*np.exp(-0.96)]*len(speclist)
        for i in range(len(speclist)):
            if Elist[i] <= 4.1357e-3: # frequencies <= 10^12 Hz
                klist[i] = 0.1*(float(Elist[i])/(1000.0*h))**beta # extinction law [cm^2/g]
            elif Elist[i] > 4.1357e-3: # frequencies > 10^12 Hz
                klist[i] = interpolate(R_V, rawpoints, Elist, i) # interpolated function's value at Elist[i]
        Mdustlist = [M_gas*DGR for DGR in DGRlist] # dust mass
        R_halo = 0.784*(0.27**2.0)*(0.7**(-2.0/3.0))*float(10/(1+z))*((M_halo/(1e8*M_sun))**(1.0/3.0))
        R_dust = 0.018*R_halo # [kpc]

        # Optical depth calculation
        Tlist = [3*Mdustlist[i]*klist[i]/(4*np.pi*R_dust) for i in range(len(speclist))]

        # Ingoing and outgoing luminosities as functions of wavelength
        Linlist = [float(spectra)*R for spectra in speclist]
        Loutlist = [Linlist[i]*np.exp(-Tlist[i]) for i in range(len(speclist))]

        return speclambdalist, Linlist, Loutlist

print dust(interpolate, filetype, datalist, beta, R, z, M_gas, M_halo, met)
```

Even when I only have the function return `Loutlist` instead of the tuple of 3 lists, it's still extremely slow. Any ideas on why this is? Also, I'm going to want to return the tuple and then plot `speclambdalist` versus `Linlist`, and also plot `speclambdalist` versus `Loutlist` on the same plot. But I'm under the impression that each time I call `dust(interpolate, filetype, datalist, beta, R, z, M_gas, M_halo, met)[i]` where `i = 0, 1, or 2` (I'll be doing this multiple times), it'll have to run the function again each time. Is there any way to bypass these extra runs to further increase speed? Thank you!

Comment: Still not readable. Functions should not be that long.

Comment: @What This doesn't address my issue of performance, firstly. Secondly, the end goal is to be able to simply call `dust(...)` with many different parameters and not have to do anything else, and unfortunately it requires many tasks/lines of code.

Comment: try to break this down in subfunctions a little. This is really hard to follow (including for yourself in 3 months time...)

Comment: It may sound unhelpful, but if your code is more maintainable, scalable and readable it is also less error-prone.

Comment: True, but wouldn't breaking it into multiple subfunctions (which would make it more readable) ultimately make my code slower? Since I'll have to call all those subfunctions in my `dust` function.

Comment: @WynneT technically yes however 1.) there must be a distinct functional change in your application that would justify the loss of speed you percieve now - functions are normally not `that` slow. 2.) There may or may not be a chance that the interpreter can optimize simpler constructs. 3.) We can debug your code faster if its less complex.

Comment: Putting code into functions doesn't slow it down signficantly, if at all.  There is something else going on here which is difficult to spot because your code is hard to follow for someone lacking your domain expertise.  I notice that in your first example you call a scipy function kinterp in one of your loops.  In the second one you call a python function interpolate in what appears to be a similar loop.  But they aren't equivalent since interpolate is a massively complicated function which does a bunch of number crunching before it calls kinterp.  That could be your performance problem.

Comment: The performance loss by breaking this up into smaller functions should be negligible imho